# How to use extract a list of keys with specific pattern from dict in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I need something that can extract a list of all keys that have the type name: **`carro_X`**, where `X` is a number. Yielding:

```
lista = ['carro_1','carro_2','carro_50']
```

from:

```
diccionario = {
    'carro_1':'renault',
    'carro_2':'audi',
    'carro_50':'sprint',
    'camioneta':'tucson'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (No need to use `iterkeys` or `keys` method; iterating dictionary yeidls keys):

```
>>> diccionario={
...     'carro_1':'renault',
...     'carro_2':'audi',
...     'carro_50':'sprint',
...     'camioneta':'tucson',
... }
>>> [key for key in diccionario if key.startswith('carro_')]
['carro_1', 'carro_50', 'carro_2']
```

**NOTE** Dictionary has no order. You need to sort the result if you want ordered result.

```
>>> sorted(['carro_1', 'carro_50', 'carro_2'], key=lambda key: int(key.split('_')[1]))
['carro_1', 'carro_50', 'carro_2']
```

**UPDATE**

To be more correct, I should take account the digits part. Use `str.isdigit` to check whether string consist of digits.

```
>>> [key for key in diccionario
...     if key.startswith('carro_') and key.split('_', 1)[1].isdigit()]
['carro_1', 'carro_50', 'carro_2']
```

Comment: With full respect to your commitment to provide professional inputs, incl. an indicated idea, here are a few facts to kindly take into account: **1st)** OP asks about regex, so you might want to know, that answering "*You don't need it*" **was frequently a subject of StackOverflow moderation penalty** as not answering the OP Task. **2nd)** the proposed syntax does not meet the OP Task Definition, as providing false outputs on ill-formed key(s) like "carro_007 e tutti quanti", that FALSE_POSITIVE(s) do not fully meet the OP Task Definition conditions.

Comment: @user3666197, Thank you for your advice. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Not sure the `SUBMARINE_carro_007_e_tutti_quanti` or `carro_008_etc` shall ever pass

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^carro_[0-9]+$')  # !match "SUBMARINE_carro_007Tutti a posto"

key_arr = [key for key in diccionario if pattern.match(key)]
```

Remember to compile pattern once and reuse it:)

Comment: `is not None` is not needed because `None` is considered as false value when used as a predicate.

Comment: If given string matches regexp it returns matcher object, else returns None, so None is correct here.

Comment: I mean you can simply express it: `key_arr = [key for key in diccionario if pattern.match(key)]`
`

Comment: BTW, you can also use `filter`: `key_arr = filter(pattern.match, diccionario)`

Comment: regex shall rather read `re.compile(r'^carro_[0-9]+$')` so as to avoid ill-formed keys from matching

Comment: @user3666197, You can omit `^` because the [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) matches pattern at the beginning of the string. See [search() vs match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Comment: Not sure, sir, it will provide a FALSE_POSITIVE(s) on `carro_747_e_carro_767_e_carro_777`

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to get carro X lets edit the dictionnary and use it like that:

```
carro = {
    1:'renault',
    2:'audi',
    50:'sprint'
}

print carro[50];
print carro[2];
```